# jQuery onclick event not works

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a lot of buttons with specific class like this:

[image]

All of these buttons has stored JSON in data attribute. I've created function, where I detect clicked button, and do some stuff with this JSON like this:

```
$(".btn-load-road").on("click", function () {
    console.log($(this).data("route"));
});
```

Click event is not fired. Can you tell me what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

> prop

method to get the value of data-route (JSON value)

Here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```
$(".btn-load-road").on("click", function () {
console.log($(this).prop("data-route"));
});
```

Comment: sorry I edit question, I mean function "on", It is on title.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in the quotation of the "data-route" value. You are trying to double-quot a string that is already doublequotted...

Instead of

```
data-route=""coordinates":[[18.159425,49.835919],...],"type":"LineString"}"
```

You could try single-quot the quoted strings inside your main string

```
data-route="{'coordinates':[[18.159425,49.835919],...],'type':'linestring'}"
```

See this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv9Lc438/)

Comment: sorry I edit question, I mean function "on", It is on title.